# Answer textbox's content starts overlapping when adding new lines in middle on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

When typing/editing an answer, sometimes if I scroll the editor textbox, go upwards and add lines, the text will start overlapping each other. The behaviour is that when you add a newline, the text below it does not move downwards.

Minimizing soft keyboard fixes this.

This does not affect the Ask Question box in my test.

[image: Bug screenshot]

I am using Android 4.1.2

Comment: [Still happening](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224815/overlapping-text-on-android-app-during-post-editing).

Comment: I concur; this is also happening with me. My phone: **Sony Xperia SP** running stock **JB4.1** rooted, **Swype** keyboard. https://www.flickr.com/x/t/0097009/photos/pepoluan/13058660985/

Comment: Not repro on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.83. Probably device/Android-dependent issue...