# Overlapping text on Android app during Post editing

Tags: bug, android-app

When I edited a post, if I **inserted** some text above existing text, eventually the inserted text will 'overlap' with the older text. See this screenshot:

> [image]

Closing and reopening the keyboard redrawn the text box to remove the 'overlapping', but it will happen again if I add more than 1 line of text.